# Correctly splitting strings after reading from file in Python

Tags: python, file, split

I'm attempting to average the lengths of each word after reading from a file. The text inside the file, however, is not formatted with normal sentence structure. Sometimes there is an extra space between words and new line breaks mid sentence.

Current code

```
def average(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            average = sum(len(words) for words in words)/len(words)
            return average

>>>4.3076923076923075

Expected
>>>4.352941176470588
```

File

```
Here are some words   there is no punctuation but there are words what
is the average length
```

Comment: please provide full code. return can only be used inside a function.

Comment: @marmeladze just edited

Comment: you say you attempting to calculate the average length of each string, do you mean words or number of words per line? Also, you might want to edit the double meaning of the name `words` in the code

Comment: average length of each word inside the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the file as `f`, then run

```
for x in f:
```

`x` will be each **line** in the file, ended by a newline. The answer you are getting is perfectly correct for the first line of text. If you want the second line to be included in the first one, you'll need to process the text file as a whole, and not line by line.

Assuming you want to get the average of all the words in the file, the following should work a little better:

```
def average(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lines = [line for line in f]
        words = " ".join(lines).split()
        average = sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)
    return average
```

Comment: would you care to provide an example? I'm fairly new to Python coming from Java

Comment: @23k are there multiple entries in the file, or is this it? If this is the only entry, just `" ".join()` each line

Comment: this is the only entry.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help :)